# Truly random number generator: python3.2 how to repeat

Tags: python, loops, random, numbers

I was creating a "truly random" number generator. This takes pythons random.randint function and uses it to generate random numbers. This turns out not to be truly random so the second code basically is trying to get the numbers only to print when the number of 0s are equal to the number of 1s and the number of 1s are equal to the number of 2s..etc..
My problem is that it doesn't loops and I am having trouble getting it to.

First code; Python randomness:

```
import random
minimum= 0
maximum= 9
howMany = int(input("How many numbers do you want to generate?"))
numZero =0
numOne = 0
numTwo = 0
numThree = 0
numFour = 0
numFive = 0
numSix = 0
numSeven = 0
numEight = 0
numNine = 0

for n in range(howMany):
    num = random.randint(minimum,maximum)
    if num == 0:
        numZero = numZero + 1
    elif num == 1:
        numOne = numOne + 1

    elif num == 2:
        numTwo = numTwo + 1
    elif num == 3:
        numThree = numThree + 1
    elif num == 4:
        numFour = numFour + 1   
    elif num == 5:
        numFive = numFive + 1
    elif num == 6:
        numSix = numSix + 1
    elif num == 7:
        numSeven = numSeven + 1
    elif num == 8:
        numEight = numEight + 1
    elif num == 9:
        numNine = numNine + 1

print ()
print ()
print ('0=', numZero)
print ('1=',numOne)
print ('2=',numTwo)
print ('3=',numThree)
print ('4=',numFour)
print ('5=',numFive)
print ('6=',numSix)
print ('7=',numSeven)
print ('8=',numEight)
print ('9=',numNine)
print ()
print ('total = ', numZero + numOne + numTwo + numThree + numFour + numFive + numSix + numSeven + numEight + numNine)
print (num)
```

Second approach, true randomness, but doesn't work like it is supposed to:

```
import random

minimum=0
maximum=9
numZero =0
numOne = 0
numTwo = 0
numThree = 0
numFour = 0
numFive = 0
numSix = 0
numSeven = 0
numEight = 0
numNine = 0
howMany = int(input("How many numbers do you want to generate?"))
def Rand():
    for n in range(howMany):
        num = random.randint(minimum,maximum)
        if num == 0:
            numZero = numZero + 1
        elif num == 1:
            numOne = numOne + 1
        elif num == 2:
            numTwo = numTwo + 1
        elif num == 3:
            numThree = numThree + 1
        elif num == 4:
            numFour = numFour + 1   
        elif num == 5:
            numFive = numFive + 1
        elif num == 6:
            numSix = numSix + 1
        elif num == 7:
            numSeven = numSeven + 1
        elif num == 8:
            numEight = numEight + 1
        elif num == 9:
            numNine = numNine + 1
        numberss = (numZero, numOne, numTwo, numThree, numFour, numFive, numSix, numSeven, numEight, numNine)
Rand()
for numbers in numberss:
    if numZero == numOne and numOne == numTwo and numTwo == numThree and numThree == numFour and numFour == numFive and numFive == numSix and numSix == numSeven and numSeven == numEight and numEight == numNine:
        print ()
        print ()
        print (numZero)
        print (numOne)
        print (numTwo)
        print (numThree)
        print (numFour)
        print (numFive)
        print (numSix)
        print (numSeven)
        print (numEight)
        print (numNine)
        print ()
        print (numZero + numOne + numTwo + numThree + numFour + numFive + numSix + numSeven + numEight + numNine)
    else:
        numZero =0
        numOne = 0
        numTwo = 0
        numThree = 0
        numFour = 0
        numFive = 0
        numSix = 0
        numSeven = 0
        numEight = 0
        numNine = 0
        print ('Not Random')
        Rand()
print (num)
```

Comment: "trying to get the numbers only to print when the number of 0s are equal to the number of 1s and the number of 1s are equal to the number of 2s..etc" Just so you know, that's the opposite of "truly random". "Truly random" sequences of numbers often have repeats, they are not constrained by rules. Also, it is impossible to make a truly random number generator, which is why I put it in quotes. What you're looking for is really "the numbers zero to nine in a random order".

Comment: Any amount of manipulation you do to Python's random number generator will just make it worse. You can't get truly random numbers from a PRNG, and the number of people with the math skills to improve on a PRNG like Python's Mersenne twister, well, doesn't include you. The only way to get "truly" random numbers from your machine is to use a hardware facility specifically designed for that purpose. How you do that varies by OS.

Comment: FYI Python provides access to the system random number generator via `SystemRandom`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom and os.urandom() https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom. However, as stated by commenters above, it doesn't sound like you really mean 'truly random', or you misunderstand what that really does mean.

Comment: for the above responses, please see             http://engineering.mit.edu/ask/can-computer-generate-truly-random-number  .... It says "You can program a machine to generate what can be called “random” numbers, but the machine is always at the mercy of its programming." "There are devices that generate numbers that claim to be truly random. They rely on unpredictable processes like thermal or atmospheric noise rather than human-defined patterns. The results might still be slightly biased towards higher numbers or even numbers, but they’re not generated by a deterministic algorithm."

Comment: it also says ". “On a completely deterministic machine you can’t generate anything you could really call a random sequence of numbers,” says Ward, “because the machine is following the same algorithm to generate them. Typically, that means it starts with a common ‘seed’ number and then follows a pattern.” The results may be sufficiently complex to make the pattern difficult to identify, but because it is ruled by a carefully defined and consistently repeated algorithm, the numbers it produces are not truly random. “They are what we call ‘pseudo-random’ numbers,” Ward says."

Comment: Therefore, if you read the article, what I am doing is making a "fake"random generator...if you print out one billion numbers, i am trying to get it so 0 is printed 100 million time, 1 is printed 100 million times, etc... all in a random order                           ... i ran a 10 billion number test on the first program and the results were                                                          0= 999987535
1= 999983580
2= 1000021085
3= 999955135
4= 1000005017
5= 999994047
6= 999985992
7= 1000006216
8= 1000051670
9= 1000009723
total =  10000000000  BTW.it can comprehend 200000 number p s

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you generate only one number. If you want to make it loop, try `for looper in range(0, 10)` That should loop 10 times. But you are changing the value every time.